# Pulseaudio use two Output devices

Tags: linux, audio, graphics-card, arch-linux, pulse-audio

I want to output my audio on two screens attached to my NVidia gk208 via DisplayPort, but pavucontrol only lets me choose one or the other. The choosing happens in the "Configuration" Tab, so paprefs do not work.

Is there any method to do this, maybe also involving a driver update of sorts?
Or is my card just not capable of doing it?

Comment: So you're trying to use two profiles of the same output sink?

Comment: I am not really sure on the terminology. My Sound card just has two speakers attached and I can only choose one at a time apparently.

Comment: That doesn't sound very usual. What output jacks on the sound card are you using (what type and color are they), and what profiles are you able to choose in pavucontrol (the part where you say "only lets me choose one or the other")?

Comment: I use Display Port, as my Displays have Speakers. The Graphics card is also able to supply both simultaneously, just pavu doesn't want that. Profiles are DP1 and DP2.